# "handshake failed" error when using openresty (resty.http)

Tags: ssl, lua, openresty

I am trying to make a call to a HTTPS upstream server in lua code in openresty. Code is as below:

```
local http = require "resty.http"

local M = {}

function M.makeHttpCall()
    local httpc = http.new()
    local res, err = httpc:request_uri("https://<url>", {
        method = "GET",
        ssl_verify = false
    })
    if not res then
        ngx.status = 500
        ngx.say("Error: ", err)
        return
    end

    .....
end
```

nginx.conf has the following relevant configuration:

```
server {
        listen 8080;
        resolver local=on ipv6=off;
        .....
        location /httpcall {
            default_type 'application/json';
            content_by_lua_block {
                require("../lua-modules/http")["makeHttpCall"]()
            }
        }
```

Following error is logged in error.log:

```
SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:SSL alert number 40), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /httpcall HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"
http.lua:15: makeHttpCall(): **request failed: handshake failed**, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /httpcall HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"
```

HTTP endpoint can be called successfully.

Any pointers to resolve the issue please?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of `lua-resty-http` are you using?

Comment: 0.16.1, the latest one revision

Comment: 0.16.1 was not yet releasted at the time you posted the question. Is the error still present? There was a bug that affected 0.16 but was fixed in 0.16.1: https://github.com/ledgetech/lua-resty-http/issues/236 https://github.com/ledgetech/lua-resty-http/releases/tag/v0.16.1